# Magento Redirect Loop - Cart Controller Overide

Tags: php, magento, http-redirect

I have created a module to add a discount code to the customers cart if they are either a new customer or have not ordered in the last 24 hours, it is for a company supplying lunch for their employees and they receive a subsidiary each day to use of £3.00.

So I have:

**app/code/local/Brave/Subsidary/controllers/CartControlller.php**

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout').DS.'CartController.php';

class Brave_Subsidary_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {

    const DISCOUNTCODE = 'BCOMSTAFF';

    public function addAction() {
        parent::addAction();
        $this->autoApplySubsidaryDiscount();
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        parent::addAction();
        $this->autoApplySubsidaryDiscount();
    }

    public function autoApplySubsidaryDiscount() {

        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId()); 

        if(!$orders->getSize()) {

            // New Customer...     
            $this->applyDiscountCoupon();

        } else {

            // Check last order date
            $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
            ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_DESC);

            $newestOrder = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();

            $dateToday = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
            $lastOrderDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(strtotime($newestOrder->getData('created_at')));

            // only apply if last order was more than 24hrs ago..
            if( $dateToday > $lastOrderDate ) {

                $this->applyDiscountCoupon();   

            }

        }

    }

    public function applyDiscountCoupon() {
        Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->setData("coupon_code",self::DISCOUNTCODE);
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode(self::DISCOUNTCODE)->save();     
    }

}
?>
```

**app/code/local/Brave/Subsidary/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brave_Subsidary>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Brave_Subsidary>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Brave_Subsidary before="Mage_Checkout">Brave_Subsidary</Brave_Subsidary>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then my module file:
**app/etc/modules/Brave_Subsidary.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Brave_Subsidary>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Brave_Subsidary>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The problem is that I am getting a redirect loop on the cart page or from adding an item to the cart, this is probably a real simple issue but trying to Google anything related this is a real needle in a haystack!

The error FireFox tells me is:

*Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.*

Comment: I can confirm that the discount code is being applied correctly, as when I disable the module the discount code is showing up as being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is:

You are calling parent:addAction() which redirects back to indexAction which is your indexAction which calles parent:addAction again...thus the redirect loop.

Bad code:

```
   public function indexAction() {
        parent::addAction();
        $this->autoApplySubsidaryDiscount();
    }
```

You must not call addAction in your above seen custom indexAction!

Solution:

1. Remove

   public function indexAction() {
    parent::addAction();
    $this->autoApplySubsidaryDiscount();
   }
2. Change

   public function addAction() {
    $this->autoApplySubsidaryDiscount();
    parent::addAction();
   }

Done.

But better instead rewriting the controller would be to use an observer...but thats another thread i guess :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, might I add that the indexAction needs to be there also but just change it to:
public function indexAction() {
$this->autoApplySubsidaryDiscount();
        parent::indexAction();
        
    }